# NTFS partition resizing wubi Ubuntu boot problem

Tags: 12.04, wubi, ntfs

After resizing the NTFS partition where wubi Ubuntu is in, or installing openSUSE 12.2, I'm not sure, my wubi ubuntu can not boot to the login screen(GUI), in the command line screen displaying a message says so such a device F39CXXXXXXXXXXXXX....What I can do to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

When you resized the partition, it was assigned a new UUID. Grub uses this to boot the Wubi install. You can manually override it with the new UUID if you know it or use the following technique to boot the Wubi install and then update grub to see the new UUID:

First you want to make the Grub menu appear so you can take control. After selecting Ubuntu, immediately hold down the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key until the menu appears.

Then either hit <kbd>E</kbd> to edit that entry, replacing the UUID with the new one, and then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>X</kbd> to boot.

Or if you don't know the new UUID, drop to a Grub prompt and manually boot the Wubi install as follows:

```
search -s -f -n /ubuntu/disks/root.disk
probe --set=diskuuid -u $root
loopback loop0 /ubuntu/disks/root.disk
set root=(loop0)
linux /vmlinuz root=UUID=$diskuuid loop=/ubuntu/disks/root.disk ro quiet splash
initrd /initrd.img
boot
```

Then after booting into Ubuntu, drop to a terminal and update grub:

```
sudo update-grub
```